# How do I replace multiple strings from one column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am working on a multiple language database.
Unfortunately, some of strings was mistakenly
inputted into the wrong language column.

I have a glossary for those strings,
but the replacement task is huge  (over 3,000).
I cannot finish the work with the Query I used before.

```
*UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    column = REPLACE(column,'BereplaceString','replaceString')
 WHERE
    locale = "XX" and 
    description like “%BereplaceString%"
```

It is possible to make the replacement task into one command?
(I can use excel to combine for the replace string,
but don't want to execute the command for a 1000 times)

Thanks for helping in advance!

Now:

```
ID     Column A         Column B
      (Langauge)     (Description)    
 
1         EN           red pomme  
2         FR           apple rouge
3         EN        yellow citron    
4         FR           lemon jaune
```

Expected Outcome:

```
ID     Column A         Column B
      (Langauge)     (Description)    
 
1         EN           red apple
2         FR           pomme  rouge
3         EN        jaune citron    
4         FR           lemon yellow
```

Comment: Do we have another language apart from french and english ? It'll be a lot messier if we have more than two languages and have lost count of how  they were mistakenly put in each other's place.

Comment: *It is possible to make the replacement task into one command?* Easily - when this command is `CALL myreplace()` where `myreplace()` is iterative stored procedure. The data for replacing should be stored into the table (locale, pattern, replacement).